# Cron files /etc/at.allow and /etc/cron.allow files, root permission abnormal behaviour?

Tags: cron, permissions, chmod

In my open vpn server, i am ensuring cron file permission to be only accessable from root user.

I have removed the `at.deny` and `cron.deny` files and have created `at.allow` and `cron.allow` and `0600 permissions` are applied for files, both files are empty and file permissions are as below, which clearly says root has read and write access.

```
-rw------- 1 root root          0 Jul 21 08:40 cron.allow
-rw------- 1 root root          0 Jul 21 08:40 at.allow
```

however this change allows my openvpnas user to still list the crontab and even allows to edit cron.

```
openvpnas@openvpnas2:~$ crontab -l
no crontab for openvpnas
```

Where as when the file permissions are as below,

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root          0 Jul 21 08:41 cron.allow
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root          0 Jul 21 08:41 at.allow
```

It restricts my non root users to access or edit cron files! This issue is only with one of my server, where as other server permissions and behaviours are as expected,

```
openvpnas@openvpnas2:~$ crontab -l
You (openvpnas) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)
See crontab(1) for more information
```

Please provide your inputs on this, this has kept me blocked from continuing  my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue i faced was in Ubuntu 18.04 instance,

Current `/usr/bin/crontab` permission was as below,

`-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 39352 Nov 16  2017 /usr/bin/crontab`

Had to change the group user from crontab to root and file permission to as below,

```
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/crontab
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/crontab

-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 39352 Nov 16  2017 /usr/bin/crontab
```

This permission restricts the non-root user to schedule cronjobs. The access can be allowed to non-root users by adding the user names in `cron.allow` file.

```
openvpnas@openvpnas2:~$ crontab -l
You (openvpnas) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)
See crontab(1) for more information
```